# Azure Service Bus "calls" are not visible on Azure Application Insights for Java applications

Tags: azure-application-insights, azureservicebus

I am using Java 17 with the Azure SDK "applicationinsights-agent-3.3.1.jar" to connect all the microservices to "Azure Application Insights".
I am using com.azure:azure-messaging-servicebus:7.8.0

The configuration seems correct since I am able to spot each microservice in the application insights view and can see the interconnections between them in the "Application Map".

The Azure Service Bus Queue is also working as expected. (I can see the app logs and the queue monitoring on the Azure Service Bus view)

**What is missing, are the arrows pointing to My "Service Bus Queue" and the queue part on the End-to-end transaction (Operation ID chaining) view.**

I am expecting something like that:

[image]
Also:
Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent#azure-sdks
We can see that *"Telemetry emitted by these Azure SDKs is automatically collected by default ... Azure Service Bus 7.1.0+"*

But here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#telemetry-correlation-in-java
"Kafka, RabbitMQ, and Azure Service Bus isn't supported in the SDK."

Thank you!